# Is there something like an ioDrive but for laptops?

Tags: laptop, ssd, hard-drive

I hear they are much faster than SSD flash.
However I must admit that I don't do a ton of disk accesses usually.

Answer (score 3):

No, because there's no interface fast enough on most laptops that an ioDrive would benefit from.

- The SATA-2 interface as 3 Gb/s of bandwidth.
- SATA-3 is 6 Gb/s.
- USB 2.0 is only 480 Mb/s.
- ExpressCard 1.0 is 2.5 Gb/s.
- USB 3.0 and ExpressCard 2.0 are both 5 Gb/s, so it could have more bandwidth.
- Finally, there's Intel's Thunderbolt, which is currently at 10 Gb/s, and has much more bandwidth.

However, raw bandwidth is only part of the equation.  Overhead and latency also plays a factor.  For USB (especially 2.0), both of those are major issues.  USB 3.0 should be better, but is expected to have a payload bandwidth of "only" ~3.2 Gb/s ([Source](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Features)).

Thunderbolt's issues are yet to be seen, but a gut guess says that latency would be slightly higher than an internal device.  How much that would impact performance at the very high end remains to be seen, but a Thunderbolt-based ioDrive should be capable of being much faster than a SATA-2 version.

Comment: hypothetically, you COULD hang memory off mini pci-e.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: Mini PCIe is only x1 -- it falls between SATA-2 and SATA-3 (assuming PCIe 2.0).  Also, mSATA uses the same physical connector as Mini PCIe, but a different logical interface to support SATA-3.

Answer (score 1):

These drives cost more than a laptop in the first place, so I doubt they made any...

[Prices...](http://www.google.com/search?q=iodrives&tbs=shop:1&aq=f&oq=&aq=f)